# Getting NZEC in KOTLIN

Tags: kotlin, runtime-error

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    var rep= readLine()?:""
    var repp= rep.toInt()

    repeat(repp){
        var n= readLine()?:""
        var num= n.toInt()
        var lastNumber= num%10
       //println(lastNumber)
        while (num>10)
            num/=10
            //println(n)
        var sum=lastNumber+num
        println(sum)
    }
}
```

I am getting NZEC(Run Time Error)

Input could be:
3
1234
21346
156797
Output should be:
5
8
8
but its showing NZEC. Can anyone please help me with it? What should i do now?

Comment: Your while loop is infinite because it doesn’t do anything to modify the condition. It’s doing a math operation but not assigning the result to the variable.

Comment: How are you running this, and what is the actual error message you're seeing? (I'm guessing ‘NZEC’ stands for ‘non-zero exit code’, but I can't see how that can happen here, as `main()` doesn't return a value, and there are no calls to `exitProcess()`).) Your (edited) code runs fine for me with your given input, showing 5, 8, and 8 as expected.